# scrolling div issue when the google map direction details are displayed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have a google map displayed with a marker which is the starting address and there is a text input which takes the destination address. When clicked on GetDirections button, i get the directions information in a div.The code as follows:
asp.net:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td width="500">
                    <div id="map-container" style="width: 500px; height: 320px; border: 1px solid black">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="280">
                    <div id="directions-panel" style="width: 90px;visibility:hidden; height: 320px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<table width="300" style="margin-left: 460px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="label">
                Enter Address To Get The Directions:</div>
            <div id="panel" style="width: 280px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #CECECE;">
                <div>
                    <input id="end" size="0"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Get Directions" onclick="reducemap();calcRoute();" style="width: 190px;
                    background: #d0cfc8; color: #000000;">
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

javascript code:

```
var lat = '<%=m_lat %>', long = '<%=m_long %>';
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() { 
var mapProp = {
                    zoom: 7,
                    panControl: true,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
                    },
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    streetViewControl: true,
                    overviewMapControl: true,
                    rotateControl: true,
                    center: myCenter,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"), mapProp);

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': myCenter }, function (results, status) {
                if (results != null) {
                    result = results[0];
                    if (result != null) {
                        var strFullAddress = '<%=m_Address %>';
                        document.getElementById('hdnUserAddress').value = strFullAddress;
                    }
                }
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myCenter,
                    title: "latlng: " + myCenter + " You are in" + document.getElementById('hdnUserAddress').value
                });

                marker.setMap(map);
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>Address</b><br/>" + document.getElementById('hdnUserAddress').value });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            });



directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function reducemap() {
            document.getElementById("map-container").style.width = "320px";
            document.getElementById("directions-panel").style.width = "280px";
            document.getElementById("directions-panel").style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    function calcRoute() {
        var start = '<%=m_Address %>';
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The issue is: When the directions are displayed,google map shows the directions with the left,right arrows in the direction-panel div and when i try to scroll the div,the arrows are not fixed,they also keep moving.I want the arrows to be fixed wherever they are when i scroll. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following in a style tag in my page after the google api script for google map loads and my issue for the browser is fixed:

```
/* Override Google Maps Icon style */
            .adp-substep .adp-stepicon .adp-maneuver {
                position: static;
            }

            /* Override Google Maps Icon Container style */
            .adp-substep .adp-stepicon{
                position: static; }
```